# RadioButtonList clear via jQuery not reflected on server side in custom control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, custom-controls

I have an existing project I need to support that has a database driven custom control (child controls are determined by DB rows). I've extended this control with success in the past, however, I've run into a problem.

I have been asked to add support for radio button lists (RBL) and check box lists (CBL).  I added the code and they show up on screen.  Everything seemed to work fine until I added a clear link for them, and, well, the RBL control value is retaining its old value in code on the server.

I put a breakpoint in LoadPostData and checked out their values.  When they have values I see an entry in the collection for it with the proper value, and when they are clear neither has an entry.  As expected.

Since the CBL works and RBL doesn't, is this one of those lovely "features" of RBLs in .Net?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: the code as requested.  I wanted to keep this identical to the actual solution, so it uses two projects.  One class project for the control, Survey, and one for the web app.  NOTE that the webapp is C#.

To reproduce:
Put a breakpoint on the return line in Save. Click both "clear" links.  Then click the save button.  The CBL value is "" while the RBL stays as "green"

Survey.vb:

```
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Public Class Survey
    Inherits WebControl
    Implements INamingContainer, IPostBackDataHandler

    Private ReadOnly rblId As String = "rbl1"
    Private ReadOnly cblId As String = "cbl1"

    Public Function Save() As Boolean
        Dim cbl = DirectCast(FindControl(cblId), CheckBoxList)
        Dim rbl = DirectCast(FindControl(rblId), RadioButtonList)

        Dim cb = cbl.SelectedValue
        Dim rdo = rbl.SelectedValue

        Return True
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
        Dim listItem As ListItem

        Dim radioButtonList As New RadioButtonList
        radioButtonList.ID = rblId
        radioButtonList.Items.Add("red")
        listItem = New ListItem("green")
        listItem.Selected = True
        radioButtonList.Items.Add(listItem)

        Dim clearLink As HtmlAnchor = CreateLink(rblId)
        Me.Controls.Add(radioButtonList)
        clearLink.Attributes("onclick") = "$('#" & radioButtonList.ClientID & " input[type=radio]').attr('checked', false);"

        Dim checkBoxList As New WebControls.CheckBoxList
        checkBoxList.ID = cblId
        checkBoxList.Items.Add("this")
        listItem = New ListItem("that")
        listItem.Selected = True
        checkBoxList.Items.Add(listItem)

        clearLink = CreateLink(cblId)
        Me.Controls.Add(checkBoxList)
        clearLink.Attributes("onclick") = "$('#" & checkBoxList.ClientID & " input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);"
    End Sub

    Public Function CreateLink(ByVal id) As HtmlAnchor
        CreateLink = New HtmlAnchor
        CreateLink.ID = "linkClear" + id
        CreateLink.HRef = "#"
        CreateLink.InnerText = "Clear selection"
        Me.Controls.Add(CreateLink)
    End Function

    Public Function LoadPostData(ByVal postDataKey As String, ByVal postCollection As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection) As Boolean Implements System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Sub RaisePostDataChangedEvent() Implements System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvent
    End Sub
End Class
```

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestCustomControl._Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Survey" Namespace="Survey" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <cc1:Survey ID="ccSurvey" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />
</asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestCustomControl
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ccSurvey.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem now? You wrote that you can see the correct values while debugging but in the subject you wrote that it is not reflected on server side.

Comment: Well, that's because the server does not know that the values were cleared. You should learn the difference between client and server side, and what ViewState does. If you want the server to know that they have been cleared you need to do a PostBack.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer 

From my question:
"the RBL control value is retaining its old value in code on the server"

The check box works fine.

Comment: @VDWWD Wow, such low blows there.  You need to learn some manners. 
 I know the difference between client and server.  Please reread the entire post.  The client clears properly.  I am posting back, otherwise I would not be looking at values in LoadPostData.

Comment: When is `you should` dealing blows? But you are right that I missed the postback part. But here comes another "blow", if you posted some code that is [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will be much easier do diagose the problem, because now it is anyones guess.

Comment: @VDWWD No, requesting an MCVE is not a blow.  Failing to read my post and making an assumption that says I need to "learn" something that I clearly understand is a bit of a blow.  

Anyway, there is no way to make this code into something I can post.  The control itself is over 1500 lines.  I was hoping someone would read my post and say "Oh, RBLs do that because..." or some such.

Comment: Are you binding the old values without an `IsPostBack` check? If so the old values will be overwritten again on PostBack.

Comment: @VDWWD In CreateChildControls I create the children and get their current value from the DB.  In my page's Load there is a check of IsPostback.  If it is false a Save method in the control is called.  Save calls FindControl and saves the new value to the DB.  In Save the CBL control is correct (no selection) but the RBL is not (old value is still there).  This page has dozens of controls and they all work fine.  It's just the RBL that persists its old value.

Comment: I am going to bite the bullet and try to reproduce this in a smaller project.

Comment: @VDWWD thanks for your help so far, I have added code that "works" as I have described in my original question.

Comment: "Works as described" meaning I was able to reproduce the issue in a stand alone, new project...so I'm still looking for a reason this is occurring.